# Sorting a collection of collections by indices of inner collection elements in Scala

Tags: scala, sorting

Let us have a collection of collections as below:

```
type Row = IndexedSeq[Any]
type RowTable = IndexedSeq[Row]

val table: RowTable = IndexedSeq(
    IndexedSeq(2, "b", ... /* some elements of type Any*/),
    IndexedSeq(1, "a", ...),
    IndexedSeq(2, "c", ...))
```

Each `Row` in `RowTable` "has the same schema", meaning that as in example if the first row in the table contains `Int, String, ...`, then the second row in the table contains the elements of the same type in the same order, i.e., `Int, String, ...`.

I would like to sort `Row`s in a `RowTable` by given indices of `Row`'s elements and the sorting direction (ascending or descending sort) for that element.

For example, the collection above would be sorted this way for Index 0 ascending and Index 1 descending and the rest of elements are not important in sorting:

```
1, "a", ...
2, "c", ...
2, "b", ...
```

Since `Row` is `IndexedSeq[Any]`, we do not know the type of each element to compare it; however, we know that it may be casted to `Comparable[Any]` and, thus, has `compareTo()` method to compare it with an element under the same index in another row.

The indices, as mentioned above, that will determine the sorting order are not known before we start sorting. How can I code this in Scala?

Comment: Having `Any` is almost always a code smell. Which usually means a design error.

Comment: This is an interop with Java and legacy code; I hate having `Any` as well :\

Comment: Is the information about which fields to sort and how to sort static or dynamic? Is the information about the number of columns and their types static or dynamic?

Comment: Both are dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Sorry for unidiomatic (maybe not compiling) code; I can probably help with it upon request)

We can use the code below to sort a table

```
table.sortWith {
   case (tupleL, tupleR) => isLessThan(tupleL, tupleR)
}
```

where `isLessThan` is defined as follows (unidiomatic to Scala, ik):

```
def isLessThan(tupleL: Row, tupleR: Row): Boolean = {
      var i = 0
      while (i < sortInfos.length) {
        val sortInfo = sortInfos(i)
        val result = tupleL(sortInfo.fieldIndex)
            .asInstanceOf[Comparable[Any]].compareTo(
          tupleR(sortInfo.fieldIndex)
            .asInstanceOf[Comparable[Any]])

        if (result != 0) {
          if (sortInfo.isDescending) {
            if (result > 0)
              return true
            else
              return false
          } else {
            if (result < 0)
              return true
            else
              return false
          }
        }

        i += 1
      }
      true
    }
```

where `sortInfos` is `IndexedSeq[SortInfo]` and

```
case class SortInfo(val fieldIndex: Int, val isDescending: Boolean)
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's a bad design to compare a pair of `Any`.

By default, scala doesn't provide any way to get `Ordering[Any]`. Hence if you want to compare a pair of `Any`, you should implement `Ordering[Any]` by yourself:

```
object AnyOrdering extends Ordering[Any] {
  override def compare(xRaw: Any, yRaw: Any): Int = {
    (xRaw, yRaw) match {
      case (x: Int, y: Int) => Ordering.Int.compare(x, y)
      case (_: Int, _) => 1
      case (_, _: Int) => -1
      ...
      case (x: String, y: String) => Ordering.String.compare(x, y)
      case (_: String, _) => 1
      case (_, _: String) => -1
      ...
      case (_, _) => 0
    }
  }
}
```

In your example, you want to compare two `IndexedSeq[T]` recursively. Scala doesn't provide any recursive `Ordering` and you need to implement it too:

```
def recOrdering[T](implicit ordering: Ordering[T]): Ordering[IndexedSeq[T]] = new Ordering[IndexedSeq[T]] {
  override def compare(x: IndexedSeq[T], y: IndexedSeq[T]): Int = compareRec(x, y)

  @tailrec
  private def compareRec(x: IndexedSeq[T], y: IndexedSeq[T]): Int = {
    (x.headOption, y.headOption) match {
      case (Some(xHead), Some(yHead)) =>
        val compare = ordering.compare(xHead, yHead)
        if (compare == 0) {
          compareRec(x.tail, y.tail)
        } else {
          compare
        }
      case (Some(_), None) => 1
      case (None, Some(_)) => -1
    }
  }
}
```

After that you can finally sort your collection:

```
table.sorted(recOrdering(AnyOrdering))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it is mentioned in the question that Any is castable to Comparable, which your answer omits. Also, it's unclear how sorting by index works in your answer.

Comment: You can't compare Comparable of different types. Hence you need to build ordering on top of types besides ordering between Comparable.

Comment: The question doesn't stay that clearly, sorry, but the ordering of elements in each subcollection is the same

Comment: Do you want an ordering that lookups for ordering for every specific type?

Comment: This is wrong. Having both `case (_: String, _) => 1` and `case (_: Int, _) => 1` makes it unpredictable, and result will depend on sorting algorithm and order of items. In principle `compare(a,b) == -compare(b,a)` should be true for any input but it will be not for any pair `(String, Int)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working Example with `Ordering[IndexedSeq[Any]]`:

```scala
val table: IndexedSeq[IndexedSeq[Any]] = IndexedSeq(
  IndexedSeq(2, "b", "a"),
  IndexedSeq(2, "b"),
  IndexedSeq("c", 2), 
  IndexedSeq(1, "c"),
  IndexedSeq("c", "c"), 
  //IndexedSeq((), "c"), //it will blow in runtime
  IndexedSeq(2, "a"),
)


implicit val isaOrdering:Ordering[IndexedSeq[Any]] = { (a, b) => 
 a.zip(b).filter {case (a, b)=> a != b}.collectFirst {
   case (a:Int, b:Int) => a compare b
   case (a:String, b:String) => a compare b
   case (a:String, b:Int) => 1 //prefere ints over strings
   case (a:Int, b:String) => -1 //prefere ints over strings
   case _ => throw new RuntimeException(s"cannot compare $a to $b")
 }.getOrElse(a.length compare b.length) //shorter will be first
}

println(table.sorted) //used implicitly
println(table.sorted(isaOrdering)) 
//Vector(Vector(1, c), Vector(2, a), Vector(2, b), Vector(2, b, a), Vector(c, 2), Vector(c, c))
```

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/yvLEnYL/4

or if you really need to compare different types somehow this is best I could find:

```scala
implicit val isaOrdering:Ordering[IndexedSeq[Any]] = { (a, b) => 
 a.zip(b).filter {case (a, b)=> a != b}.collectFirst {
   case (a:Int, b:Int) => a compare b
   case (a:String, b:String) => a compare b
   //add your known types here
   // ...
   //below is rule that cares about unknown cases. 
   //We don't know types at all, at best what we can do is compare equality.
   //If they are equal then return 0... if not we throw
   //this could be also very slow (don't tested)  
   case (a, b) => 
   //not nice but it is stable at least
    val ac = a.getClass.getName
    val bc = b.getClass.getName
    ac.compare(bc) match {
      case 0 => if (ac == bc) 0 else throw new RuntimeException(s"cannot compare $a to $b")
      case x => x
    } 
 }.getOrElse(a.length compare b.length) //shorter will be first
}
```

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/yvLEnYL/5

This implementation will fail in runtime when we could not compare them.